# How to find the count of similar data in a column of table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

suppose i have a one tables having 3 column in name,email,token in mySQL

now i want to find the count of all that fields which have similar token number

please guide Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count, use [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) function

```
SELECT token, COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY token
```